# is there a way to get min and max attribute in a lightning:input in js controller in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, aura-attribute, lightninginput

```
<lightning:input type="number" name="min_perc"  aura:id="required" required="true" class="label-text minPerc" min="0" max="99" value="{!v.min_perc}" messageWhenRangeOverflow="Value out of range" messageWhenRangeUnderflow="Value out of range"  autocomplete="off" onchange="{!c.onChangePerc}" onblur="{!c.checkValidity}" step="1"/>
```

```
<lightning:input type="number" name="max_perc"  aura:id="required" required="true" class="label-text maxPerc" value="{!v.max_perc}"  min = "0" max="99"  messageWhenRangeOverflow="Value out of range" messageWhenRangeUnderflow="Value out of range"   autocomplete="off" step="1" onblur="{!c.checkValidity}" onchange="{!c.onChangePerc}"/>
```

Hi I have this 2 lightning:input in aura component and I want to be able to change the min and max values in js controller, I've also tried setting them using a ternary operation like  `min = "{!v.min_perc ? v.min_perc + 1 : 0 }"` but it doesn't seem to work I can't use aura:id since all the lightning:input have the same id that i use in another logic. I've also tried document.getElementsByClassname or something like `var minOfMin = component.find('min_perc').get('v.min');` but again it doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can able to update the min and max properties of the Lightning input field, Try the below.

.cmp File:

```
<lightning:input type="number" name="min_perc"  aura:id="one-id"  onchange="{!c.onChangePerc}" min="2" max="998" value="0" required="true" class="label-text minPerc" 
 messageWhenRangeOverflow="Value out of range" messageWhenRangeUnderflow="Value out of range"  
                     autocomplete="off" />
```

controller.js:

```
({
onChangePerc : function(component, event, helper) {
    var myEle = component.find("one-id");
    console.log("Element:" +myEle);
    
    var myAttri = component.find("one-id").get("v.value");
    console.log("Value:"+ myAttri);
    
    var myAttriMin = component.find("one-id").get("v.min");
    console.log("Min:"+myAttriMin);       
    component.find("one-id").set("v.min", parseInt(myAttriMin)+1);
    myAttriMin = component.find("one-id").get("v.min");
    console.log("MinAfter:"+myAttriMin);       
    
    var myAttriMax = component.find("one-id").get("v.max");
    console.log("Mzx:"+myAttriMax);
    component.find("one-id").set("v.max", parseInt(myAttriMax)+1);
    myAttriMax = component.find("one-id").get("v.max");
    console.log("MaxAfter:"+myAttriMax);  
    

}
```

})

Inspector Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @Testing1002  and also you can use generic variables if you are about to change the min and max for all the input numbers in your component instead of changing elements by elements

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: @Testing1002 Glad, It helped you.